# How to model $\| z\|_1^2$ in the objective of a quadratic program?

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

I want to write a quadratic program to the problem

$$\text {minimize}_{z\in\mathbb{R}^d} \|z\|_1^2 + F(z)$$

where $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the $l_1$ norm and $F$ is some function. How can I do that?

---

Attempt:

Define $t_j:=|z_j|$. (We can constraint $t_j\geq \pm z_j$. Hence,
$$
||z||_1^2=(\sum_{j\leq d}|z_j|)^2
\\=(\sum_{j\leq d}t_j)^2=\sum_{k,l\leq d}t_kt_l=t\cdot t^T
$$
But I'm not sure how it could help.

Comment: Can you give a little more context about what you mean by "quadratic"? If $F$ is not quadratic itself, what do you expect to gain?

Comment: Quadratic program (QP) is an optimiztaion problem of the form $$\text{minimize}_{x\in\mathbb R^n} x^THx+\langle x,u\rangle
\\ \text{s.t. }Ax\geq v$$
for some $H\in\mathbb R^{n\times n},u\in\mathbb R^n, A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}, v\in\mathbb R^m$.
I don't really care about $F$ (in my original problem) because this is a function I know how to model inside the QP. (For example, if we really want we can set $F(z)$ to be $z^Tz$). Hence, my question is regard to $||z||_1^2$: If we ignore $F$, how can I model the problem $\text{minimize} _{z\in\mathbb R^d}||z||_1^2$ as a QP?